# Make a CCSprite come up from bottom of the screen in intervals

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, ccsprite

I have a cocos2d iOS app. I have a CCSprite that I need to come up from the bottom of the screen every few seconds (like 2 or 3 seconds). How would I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It really helps us to answer your questions if we have something to build off of, instead of just guessing what you have. (Please don't post all your source code). Help us help you.

Comment: @Byte56 I ask because I do not know how to 1. Move a CCSprite across a screen smoothly 2. Do things in intervals

Comment: Then your question doesn't show any research effort. What have you researched?

Comment: @Byte56 I dont know how to make the ccsprite move smoothly across the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [these](http://www.iphonegametutorials.com/tutorials/#beginner) tutorials (the beginner ones). Your question sounds like you're getting ahead of yourself. If you don't know how to move a sprite, or time things or do things in intervals, you shouldn't be asking how to do all three at the same time. Take a step back, get comfortable with the basics. If you have a specific issue you're having trouble with, post another question here and we can help.